# In R, how to drop the duplicates bases on two columns the values of which are probably exchangeable?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, group-by, duplicates

My sample data is:

```
a <- data.frame(a1=c('a','b','c','d','e'),
                a2=c('b','a','d','c','f'),
                a3=c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.1,1))
```

What I want to do is combine the columns a1 and a2, and sort the strings at the same time. So, the data should change to:

```
  a1 a2  a3  a12
1  a  b 0.1  a,b
2  b  a 0.3  a,b
3  c  d 0.5  c,d
4  d  c 0.1  c,d
5  e  f 1.0  e,f
```

After sorting, we can see the rows 1 and 2 are actually in one group, so are the rows 3 and 4. Then for every group, I just want to keep the row with the biggest a3. So, in the end, the data should be like:

```
  a1 a2  a3  a12
2  b  a 0.3  a,b
3  c  d 0.5  c,d
5  e  f 1.0  e,f
```

I stuck with how to sort a1 and a2. Is there any quick way to do this?

Comment: thanks a lot for all you guy's help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the values in `a1` and `a2` column using `pmin` and `pmax` and group them to select `max` value in each group.

```
library(dplyr)
a %>%
   group_by(a11 = pmin(a1, a2), a22 = pmax(a1, a2)) %>%
   slice(which.max(a3)) %>%
   tidyr::unite(a12, a11, a22, sep = ',')

#   a1    a2     a3 a12  
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#1 b     a       0.3 a,b  
#2 c     d       0.5 c,d  
#3 e     f       1   e,f
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort` and `paste` in `apply` to get `a12`. And then use `which.max` to get the line where `a3` is max and return this.

```
a$a12 <- apply(a[1:2], 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=","))
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(a, a$a12), function(x) x[which.max(x$a3),]))
#    a1 a2  a3 a12
#a,b  b  a 0.3 a,b
#c,d  c  d 0.5 c,d
#e,f  e  f 1.0 e,f
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are after:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

a <- tibble(a1=c('a','b','c','d','e'),
                a2=c('b','a','d','c','f'),
                a3=c(0.1,0.3,0.5,0.1,1))

a <- a %>%
  mutate(a12 = ifelse(a1 < a2, paste0(a1, ",", a2), paste0(a2, ",", a1))) %>%
  group_by(a12) %>%
  filter(a3 == max(a3))

> a
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   a12 [3]
  a1    a2       a3 a12  
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1 b     a       0.3 a,b  
2 c     d       0.5 c,d  
3 e     f       1   e,f
```